# MySQL update first set of rows from another table valueone and then second set of rows from valuetwo and so on

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables named as patients and doctors.

patients table fields are:  patientname,
patientid,
doctorid

doctors table fields are : doctorname,
doctorid,

Let I have 100 patients  and 10 doctors, Now I have to assign 10 patients to each doctor, How can I update patient table to update doctorid for each patient.

I want first 10 patients should be assigned to doctor1 and next 10 patients be assigned to doctor2 and so on......

How can I update patient table so that  doctorid is updated for each patient in patient table.(MySQL statement)

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. First thing is you'll have to decide which patients are "first".

Comment: Patients are in ascending ordered according to their patientid. Let patientid 1 to 10 are first and patientid 11 to 20 are second and so on...

Comment: Replace the numbers 100, 10, and 10 with 13, 3, and 4, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Firstly collect all doctor id from doctor table and store it in an array then iterate following steps for each doctor id through a programatic loop
Intially doctorid corresponnding to all patients will be
null.
then use the query

```
update patient set doctorid=[iterated value from the array] where doctorid is NULL LIMIT 10
```

in the next iteration through the next doctorid the previously doctorid assigned patients will be skipped since their doctorid is not null. By this way we can assign doctorid to all the patientss

Comment: Thanks bro I got idea, Can you please little explain how to get "iterated value form array"  . Any example